# Programmatically determine active configuration

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there a way to determine the active configuration (that means Debug or Release) in code? Something along the lines of

```
#ifdef XCodeConfigurationDebug
    ...  
#endif  

#ifdef XCodeConfigurationRelease
    ...  
#endif
```

I know that it's possible to do this by adding custom compiler flags. However, I'm looking for a more global solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the flag `__OPTIMIZE__` that is defined when on RELEASE mode, and so:

```
#ifndef __OPTIMIZE__
// code for debug mode
#else
// code for release
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

i figure it out using the preprocessor declarations. you can add your own definition, or NDEBUG is another common one to declare in release.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, but I was looking for a way that doesn't involve fiddling with the build settings. I need this for some fragment of code that will be included in another XCode project, I don't know the build settings of which. But, thx anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add your own preprocessor macros per configuration on your target's build settings. Ex.:

Debug

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
```

Release

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = RELEASE=1
```

And then in your code

```
#ifdef DEBUG
...
#else
...
#endif
```